# Why do we feel cool after switching fan?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life, flow, evaporation, fan

Please see that my actual question is not similar to this: [Why do we feel cool when we turn our fans on?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/281875/326901)

Suppose I switched my fan on. The air particles start moving. Since, their kinetic energy increase, their temperature should so for some time . Since there temperature increases, then there should be a heat transfer from air surroundings to our body( because heat flows from hotter region to colder region) . Hence, we should ***always*** feel warm when we switch fan on.

Is evaporation the only cause for it? Then why do I feel warm when riding a bicycle in an open field in a hot summer day?

Comment: When you ride your bike you are creating heat in your body by pedaling and this counteracts the cooling by evaporation. If you glide down a long hill, the breeze would have a cooling effect, no?

Comment: while riding bike, I believe that I feel warm due to air only. it feels like 'hot' particles are colliding my face.

Comment: You are forgetting that your body also has a temperature and that temperature is almost always warmer than the air. The random velocities that result in net zero movement which we typically associate with temperature are *much* faster and therefore of much higher kinetic energy than those that result in net movement like wind unless you are supersonic jet. The energy contributed from the motion of a regular breeze is negligible in comparison to that of the temperature. You might be interested in this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/675754/what-is-cold-wind/675760#675760